# Need users to be able to add extra input fields on visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, dynamic-visualforce

I have a visualforce page with a table in it with three lines that the user can fill in... it seems now that 3 lines is not enough, some users wanting up to ten. I do not want to add ten lines if I can avoid it I would rather there was an option to add an extra line to the table if the end user needs to..

I have no idea how to go about this any help would be appreciated

See image for example of what I would like :-

[image]

```
   <tr valign="top">
                            <td>1*</td>
                            <td><apex:inputText value="{!sfw.serialNumber1}" id="serialNumber1" styleclass="imInput imInput_0"/></td>
                            <td><apex:inputText value="{!sfw.modelNumber1}" id="modelNumber1" styleclass="imInput imInput_0"/></td>
                            <td><apex:inputTextArea value="{!sfw.errorDescription1}" id="errorDescription1" styleclass="imInput imInput_0" rows="4" cols="15" style="height: 60px; " /></td>
                        </tr>                            
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td><apex:inputText value="{!sfw.serialNumber2}" id="serialNumber2" styleclass="imInput imInput_0"/></td>
                            <td><apex:inputText value="{!sfw.modelNumber2}" id="modelNumber2" styleclass="imInput imInput_0"/></td>
                            <td><apex:inputTextArea value="{!sfw.errorDescription2}" id="errorDescription2" styleclass="imInput imInput_0" rows="4" cols="15" style="height: 60px; " /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td><apex:inputText value="{!sfw.serialNumber3}" id="serialNumber3" styleclass="imInput imInput_0"/></td>
                            <td><apex:inputText value="{!sfw.modelNumber3}" id="modelNumber3" styleclass="imInput imInput_0"/></td>
                            <td><apex:inputTextArea value="{!sfw.errorDescription3}" id="errorDescription3" styleclass="imInput imInput_0" rows="4" cols="55" style="height: 60px; " /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table><br/>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class ServiceFormController {

  public ServiceFormWrapper sfw { get; set; }
   public ServiceFormEmailHandler sfeh { get; set; }

public ServiceFormController() {
  sfw = new ServiceFormWrapper();
    sfw.language = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('lang');
    if (sfw.language != null) {
      sfw.language = sfw.language.toLowerCase();
    }
    sfw.processed = 'false';
    sfw.hasErrors = false;
    sfw.imageFile = new Attachment();
    setInvalidLanguageCode();
    setAgreeToConditions();
}

  private void setInvalidLanguageCode() {
    if (sfw.language != 'be' && sfw.language != 'en' && sfw.language !      = 'es' && sfw.language != 'de' && sfw.language != 'fr'      && sfw.language != 'it' && sfw.language != 'nl' && sfw.language != 'pt') {
             sfw.language = 'en';
    }
  }

  // The following languages do not have an Agree to Conditions checkbox on the form. Therefore it is set to TRUE by default.
  private void setAgreeToConditions() {
    if (sfw.language == 'de' || sfw.language == 'it' || sfw.language == 'es' || sfw.language == 'pt') {
        sfw.agreeToConditions = true;
    }
  }

public PageReference save() {

    sfw.hasErrors = false;
    if (sfw.imageFile == NULL) {
      sfw.imageFile = new Attachment();
    }

// Check that all mandatory fields have been filled in on the form. If not, display an error
    if (!ServiceFormBusinessRules.validateMandatoryFields(sfw)) {
      initiateError(Label.Error_Message);
        return null;
    }

    // Validate that the User does check the Agree to Conditions field (NOTE: not applicable for DE, IT, ES and PT) 
    if (!sfw.agreeToConditions) {
      initiateError(Label.Error_Message);
  return null;
    } 

// Validate the file if a file has been uploaded
if (sfw.imageFile.Name != NULL) {
    // Validate that the file is less than 10MB in size
    if (!ServiceFormBusinessRules.validateImageFileSize(sfw)) {
      initiateError(Label.Invalid_File_Size);
        return null;
    }
}

// Validate that the email address entered is a valid email address 
    if (sfw.emailAddress != '' && !Pattern.matches('^[a-zA-Z][\\w\\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\\w\\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\\.]*[a-zA-Z]$', sfw.emailAddress)) {
        initiateError(Label.Email_Error_Message);
        return null;
    }

    if (sfw.serviceType == 'Storing melden' &&  ((!(sfw.serialNumber2 != '' && sfw.modelNumber2 != '' && sfw.errorDescription2 != '') && !(sfw.serialNumber2 == '' && sfw.modelNumber2 == '' && sfw.errorDescription2 == '')) || (!(sfw.serialNumber3 != '' && sfw.modelNumber3 != '' && sfw.errorDescription3 != '') && !(sfw.serialNumber3 == '' && sfw.modelNumber3 == '' && sfw.errorDescription3 == '')))) {
        initiateError(Label.Report_Fault_Error_Message);
        return null;    
    }

    sfw.errorMessage = '';
ServiceFormBusinessRules.populateEnteredData(sfw);
    sfw.processed = 'true';
sfeh = new ServiceFormEmailHandler(sfw);
sfeh.sendServiceAndUserEmail();
    sfw.imageFile = null;
    return null;
}

public PageReference reset() {
  sfw = new ServiceFormWrapper();
    return null;
}

private void initiateError(String errorMessageLabel) {
  sfw.hasErrors = true;
  sfw.processed = 'false';
    sfw.imageFile = null;
  sfw.errorMessage = errorMessageLabel;
}
}
```

Wrapper

```
public with sharing class ServiceFormWrapper {

public String language { get; set; }

public String errorMessage { get; set; }
public String processed { get; set; }
public boolean hasErrors { get; set; }    

public String serviceTypeTranslated { get; set; }
public String problemReportedTranslated { get; set; }
public String haveContractTranslated { get; set; }
public String callBackTranslated { get; set; }
public String equipmentAmountTranslated { get; set; }

public String companyName { get; set; }
public String contactPerson { get; set; }
public String addressStreet { get; set; }
public String addressCodeCity { get; set; }
public String phoneNumber { get; set; }
public String emailAddress { get; set; }
public String openingTimes { get; set; }
public String serviceType { get; set; }
public String serialNumber1 { get; set; }
public String modelNumber1 { get; set; }
public String errorDescription1 { get; set; }
public String serialNumber2 { get; set; }
public String modelNumber2 { get; set; }
public String errorDescription2 { get; set; }
public String serialNumber3 { get; set; }
public String modelNumber3 { get; set; }
public String errorDescription3 { get; set; }
public String reference { get; set; }
public String poValue { get; set; }
public String problemReported { get; set; }
public String equipmentAmount { get; set; }
public String numberOfCardio { get; set; }
public String numberOfStrength { get; set; }
public String haveContract { get; set; }
public String request { get; set; }
public String callBack { get; set; }
public String sparePartItemCode1 { get; set; }
public String sparePartItemQuantity1 { get; set; }
public String sparePartItemCode2 { get; set; }
public String sparePartItemQuantity2 { get; set; }
public String sparePartItemCode3 { get; set; }
public String sparePartItemQuantity3 { get; set; }
public String sparePartItemCode4 { get; set; }
public String sparePartItemQuantity4 { get; set; }
public String sparePartItemCode5 { get; set; }
public String sparePartItemQuantity5 { get; set; }
public String sparePartItemCode6 { get; set; }
public String sparePartItemQuantity6 { get; set; }
public String sparePartItemCode7 { get; set; }
public String sparePartItemQuantity7 { get; set; }
public String sparePartItemCode8 { get; set; }
public String sparePartItemQuantity8 { get; set; }
public String sparePartItemCode9 { get; set; }
public String sparePartItemQuantity9 { get; set; }
public String sparePartItemCode10 { get; set; }
public String sparePartItemQuantity10 { get; set; }
public boolean agreeToConditions { get; set; }

public String comments { get; set; }

public Attachment imageFile { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: This can be done within your apex controller. Can you post the relevant apex code?

Comment: I have posted the Controller and Wrapper for the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bob Buzzard wrote a great blog about this several years ago.
http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2011/07/managing-list-of-new-records-in.html

It describes how to implement the add rows type of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Oops! I am little late to this but still here is my code.

VF mark up

```
<apex:page controller="Exponential" >
<apex:form >
    <apex:actionFunction name="newItem" action="{!addNew}" reRender="tab1" oncomplete="alert('done');"/>
  <apex:pageBlock title="Viewing Accounts">
    <apex:pageBlockTable id="tab1" value="{!recList}" var="rec">
    <apex:column >
    <apex:inputText id="one" value="{!rec.one}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column >
    <apex:inputText id="two" value="{!rec.two}"/>
    </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    <apex:commandButton onclick="myScript();return false;" value="Add one"/>

  </apex:pageBlock>
  <script>
  function myScript()
  {
  alert("called");
  newItem();
  }
  </script>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class Exponential {
    public OneRecord rec{get;set;}
    public List<OneRecord> recList{get;set;}
public Exponential(ApexPages.StandardController std)
{

}
    public Exponential()
{
    recList = new List<OneRecord>();
    OneRecord new1 = new OneRecord();
    OneRecord new2 = new OneRecord();
    OneRecord new3 = new OneRecord();
        recList.add(new1);
    recList.add(new2);
    recList.add(new3);
}
  public  class OneRecord{
        public String one{get;set;}
        public String two{get;set;}
        public OneRecord()
        {

        }
    }
    public PageReference addNew()
    {
        OneRecord newone = new OneRecord();
        recList.add(newone);
        return null;
    }

}
```